# How to change product url by id to name in opencart?

Tags: opencart

the defult url of a product  is =

http://localhost/OpenCartDesign/upload/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=64

I want to change this in http://localhost/OpenCartDesign/upload/index.php?route=product/product&product_name= here show product name not product id

Answer (score 0):

Rename `/OpenCartDesign/upload/.htaccess.txt` to `/OpenCartDesign/upload/.htaccess`. Inside **Dashboard** go to `System > Settings > Action: Edit (Store) > Server (tab) > Use SEO URLs: YES` and click the **SAVE** button.

Then you will have this http://localhost/OpenCartDesign/upload/product-name which is much better for **SEO**.

Comment: thanks for Reply but this is not show that product those under in subcategories .

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about, because if you have category > subcategory the url will be something like this http://localhost/OpenCartDesign/upload/category-name/subcategory-name/product-name. Isn't that what you are looking for? If not, edit your question and add more details!

Comment: sorry your right sir this is my mistack  but product is not show only url is localhost/OpenCartDesign/upload/category-name/subcategory-na‌​me/ but page show these Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6. what can i do for this

Comment: Rename `/OpenCartDesign/upload/.htaccess.txt` to `/OpenCartDesign/upload/.htaccess`. Mind the **.** (dot) before **htaccess**.